# An html/php email form on my website is redirecting to an error page

Tags: php, html

I'm new to PHP. I'm working on a website for a personal project, and I'm trying to make a form to contact me by sending an email. I'm using Vercel with Github redirecting to a domain from GoDaddy. When I press the send button, it takes me to a page that says:

This site can’t be reached
The webpage at https://www.mydomainname.com/send_message.php might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE

I've tried reloading the page, waiting a bit and reloading again, checking to make sure the names of the files are right, and checking the folder structure, and when I check my email, it hasn't gone through. It worked at some point in time when I was using GoDaddy's site builder with their domain, but they were charging me too much so I had to switch. Does anyone see something I missed? Is it more likely to be an error within the PHP file or a problem with Vercel/GoDaddy not being able to run it properly?

This is the HTML code:

```
<form method="POST" name="myemailform" action="send_message.php">
     <div>
          <input class="input" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
     </div>
     <div>
          <input class="input" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
     </div>
     <div>
          <input class="input" type="text" name="phoneNum" placeholder="Phone Number" />
     </div>
     <div>
          <input class="message-box input" type="text" name="message" placeholder="Message" />
     </div>
     <div class="d-flex ">
          <input class="button" type="submit" value="SEND" />
     </div>
</form>
```

This is the PHP code:

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$email_from = "myemailaddress@gmail.com]";
$email_subject = "Contact Message";
$email_body = "New message from $name\n
               email address: $visitor_email\n
               message: \n
               $message";

$to = "myemailaddress@gmail.com";
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body);

?>

<script>
window.location.href="contact.html?result=success"
</script>
```

Comment: Could be  DNS issue, or just the URL is wrong. It's one of those errors that can cover different possibilities unfortunately